# How do I access an uploaded file with Bottle?

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle

I'd like to upload a text file with bottle, and then read it. How can I do this? Below is what I've tried and didn't work.

HTML:

```
<form action="/load_from_file" method="post">
  <div>
    Load File: <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Bottle route:

```
@post('/load_from_file')
def load_from_file():
    list_file = request.forms.get("file")
    print request.files.get("file")
    print request.files["file"]
    return "how do I get the uploaded file?"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form tag.

Comment: This works, thanks. I'll add that "request.files.get("file")" seems to be the right syntax to get the file.